# UISegmentedControl with rounded corner and non proportional segments bug

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

i recently updated a rounded corner segment control to have different width for each segment.
the issue i have is that the last segment doesn't align properly with the end of the segmented control

[image]

i just used this code for this sample (seg being my segmented control) :

```
seg.layer.borderWidth = 1
seg.layer.cornerRadius = seg.bounds.height / 2
seg.layer.masksToBounds = true
seg.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
```

if i remove the masksToBounds line i can see that the right segment doesn't reach the edge of the segmented control.

[image]

is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is caused by a rendering bug in `UISegmentedControl` when `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true`. I couldn't find a simple workaround by manipulating the `CALayer`s of the control. You can create a custom control using `UIStackView` to mimic the `UISegmentedControl`.

You should also file a radar with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this still affects iOS, but a workaround in Xamarin.iOS is: 
Override `UISegmentView`, calculate text width of the last segment element and update it's width.
Sample code in C#:

```
public class MySegmentedControl : UISegmentedControl
{
    public override void MovedToSuperview ()
    {
        // Fix truncation of last element
        // when ApportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
        if (ApportionsSegmentWidthsByContent) {
            RecalculateLastSegmentWidth ();
        }
    }

    private void RecalculateLastSegmentWidth()
    {
        var font = UIFont.FromName("Helvetica", 12);
        var lastSegment = NumberOfSegments - 1;
        var segmentTitle = TitleAt(lastSegment);
        var segmentWidth = segmentTitle.StringSize(font).Width + 20;
        SetWidth(segmentWidth, lastSegment);   
    }
}
```